# when trying to test my hapijs application "register" [1]: -- missing --

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, hapi.js

I am using `hapijs` `v17.2.3` . Also I am very new to hapi .I am trying to test my code using **`Lab`** a simple test utility for Node.js and **`code`** assertion library.

**my test.js file is :**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var dotEnvPath = path.resolve('./.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: dotEnvPath });
const Code = require('code');
const Lab = require('lab');
const lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
const describe = lab.describe;
const it = lab.it;
const expect = Code.expect;
const Joi = require('joi');
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const app = require('../app');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
const getServer = async () => {
    const server = new Hapi.Server();
    // server.connection();
    return server.register(app)
        .then(() => server);
};

lab.experiment('signup testing in "/signup"', () => {

    lab.test('Return true if the user can successfully signup', (done, flags) => {
        const signUpData = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/signup',
            payload: {
                name: 'vulcan',
                password: 'vulcan@123',
                email: 'vulcan@gmail.com',
                username: 'vulcan123',
                dob: '12-08-1994'
            }
        };

        getServer()
            .then((server) => server.inject(signUpData))
            .then((response) => {

                flags.note(`demo test note`);

                if (response) {
                    console.log(response.statusCode);
                    Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(201);
                    Code.expect(payload).to.contain(['name', 'password', 'email', 'username', 'dob']);

                }
                done();
            });
    });

});

lab.experiment('1) login test ', () => {
    lab.test('login has successfully done', (done) => {
        const loginData = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/login',
            payload: {
                email: 'wrong email',
                login_password: 'wrong password',
            }
        };
        getServer()
            .then((server) => {
                server.inject(loginData)
            })
            .then((response) => {
                Code.expect(response.statusCode).to.equal(200);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

> my test command is : **lab --assert code --coverage -t 100**

**my signup controller is :**

```
exports.postForm = {
    description: 'Submit the signup page',
    tags: ['api'],
    notes: 'accepts name password verify and email',
    auth: {
        mode: 'try',
        strategy: 'session'
    },
    validate: {
        payload: {
            name: Joi.string().required(),
            password: Joi.string().min(4).max(20).required(),
            verify: Joi.string().required(),
            email: Joi.string().email().required(),
            username: Joi.string().min(3).max(20).required(),
            referredBy: Joi.any(),
            dob: Joi.date().required().label('Date of Birth')
        },
        failAction: (request, h, error) => {
            console.log('Validation Failed');
            request.yar.flash('error', error.details[0].message.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
            return h.redirect('/signup').takeover();
        }
    },
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        try {
            var user = {
                name: request.payload.name,
                password: request.payload.password,
                email: request.payload.email,
                username: request.payload.username.toLowerCase(),
                referralName: request.payload.username + '@gg',
                emailConfirmationToken: uuidv1(),
                dob: request.payload.dob,
                tnc: true
            };
            let data = await signupHelper.signUpUser(user, request);
            if (data.statusCode === 201) {

                if (request.payload.referredBy) {
                    let configureReferral = await signupHelper.configureReferral(request.payload.referredBy, data.userId);
                    if (configureReferral.statusCode === 200) {
                        request.yar.flash('success', 'Account created, Please Login');
                        return h.redirect('/login');
                    }
                }
                request.yar.flash('success', 'Account created, Please Login');
                return h.redirect('/login');
            } else {
                request.yar.flash('error', data.message);
                return h.redirect('/signup');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error);

            return h.redirect('/signup');
        }
    }
};
```

**my login control :**

```
exports.login = {
    description: 'Post to the login page',
    notes: 'Accepts two paramters email and password which got validation',
    tags: ['api'],
    auth: {
        mode: 'try',
        strategy: 'session'
    },
    plugins: {
        crumb: {
            key: 'crumb',
            source: 'payload',
        },
        'hapi-auth-cookie': {
            redirectTo: false
        }
    },
    validate: {
        payload: {
            email: Joi.string().min(3).email().required(),
            login_password: Joi.string().min(4).required()
        },
        failAction: (request, h, error) => {
            request.yar.flash('error', error.details[0].message.replace(/['"]+/g, ''));
            return h.redirect('/login').takeover();
        }
    },
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        try {
            const next = request.query.next ? request.query.next : '/dashboard';

            if (request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
                return h.redirect(next);
            }
            let resultData = await loginHelper.findByCredentials(request.payload.email, request.payload.login_password);
            if (resultData.statusCode === 200) {
                request.cookieAuth.set(resultData.user);
                return h.redirect(next);
            } else {
                request.yar.flash('error', resultData.message);
                return h.redirect('/login');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(error);
            request.yar.flash('error', error.message);
            return h.redirect('/login');
        }
    }
};
```

**this is the error when I run the test:**

```
Socket server start initiated
Socket server started
Server started at https://127.0.0.1:8000
signup testing in "/signup"
  ✔ 1) Return true if the user can successfully signup (3615 ms)
1) login test
  ✖ 2) login has successfully done
(node:9708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid plugin options {
  "plugin": {
    "sock": {
      "init": function (server, options) {\n
..........
..........
},
      "register" [1]: -- missing --
      }
    }

    [1] "register" is required
        at new AssertionError (internal/errors.js:102:11)
        at Object.exports.assert (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gamergully/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:517:11)
        at Object.exports.apply (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gamergully/node_modules/hapi/lib/config.js:22:10)
        at internals.Server.register (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gamergully/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:410:31)
        at getServer (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gamergully/test/tests-signup.js:23:19)
        at lab.test (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gamergully/test/tests-signup.js:115:9)
        at Immediate.setImmediate [as _onImmediate] (/home/jeslin/projects/hapi/gamergully/node_modules/lab/lib/runner.js:628:31)
        at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
    (node:8764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
    (node:8764) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    Mongo Database connected
```

> when I run only one test case, it wont return any error. If I run more
>   than one this error is showing

I have done this by following [**this**](https://medium.com/human-stack-tutorial/human-stack-tutorial-short-introduction-to-lab-and-hapi-c8d7d5c3fbde) link

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @metoikos I have added the error that generated when run the test

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to your server instance creation. In one test you are trying to create more than one server instance with the same configuration. That might be the problem I think. When I create tests, I am using lab.before and lab.beforeEach methods to create instances.

Here is a real-world test case from one of my projects.

```
const Lab = require('lab');
const lab = exports.lab = Lab.script();
const describe = lab.describe;
const it = lab.it;
const before = lab.before;
const after = lab.after;
const expect = require('code').expect;
// ..... other stufff

describe('Test Routes', () => {

    let server;

    before(async () => {
        server = new Hapi.Server();    
        await server.register(app)                        
    });


    after(async () => {        
        await server.stop();        
    });

    it('It should obtain valid response', async () => {
        const qs = querystring.stringify(queryParams);
        const res = await server.inject({
            url: `/s?${qs}`,
            method: 'get',
            headers: {
                "Cookie": "user=aighaeshaighaPopaGoochee8ahlei8x"
            }
        });
        expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(res.result.userid).to.exist();
        expect(res.result.status).to.equal(true);


        // handle play action
        const res2 = await server.inject({
            url: `/b?id=${res.result.userid}`,
            method: 'get'
        });
        expect(res2.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(res2.result.status).to.equal(true);
    });

    //
    it('It should reject invalid request', async () => {
        const res = await server.inject({
            url: `/a?a=b&id=iChah3Ahgaaj2eiHieVeem6uw2xaiD5g`,
            method: 'get'
        });
        expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(res.result.status).to.equal(false);
        expect(res.result.message).to.equal("Invalid information");
    });

    // ... goes on
});
```

Just pay attention to `before` and `after` calls. I am creating only one instance of server then using it along side my test cases or use beforeEach and afterEach to isolate your instances, it's your choice.